# startActivityForResult() is not pausing previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I have Activities A, B, and C. A starts B and C, one after the other. The problem is that B is opened, then C starts and covers B. I want A to wait until B has finished and returned, but that is not happening. C starts immediately after starting B, so the user never sees B.

I am using startActivityForResult() as suggested in other posts, but that is not helping.

Here is the code in Activity A:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (! pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS), 1);
}
```

...

```
startActivity(new Intent(InitActivity.this, MyAwesomeActivity.class));
```

Comment: show how you start B and C. You have to start C in `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to chain the activities using `onActivityResult()`.

A calls B, then in `onActivityResult()` you use the resultCode parameter to verify that B is returning. Once verified that you are in the callback from B, then you call C. So it's more like A starts B, then B starts C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `startActivityForResult`. You have to basically do the following three steps:

1. `startActivityForResult(intent_A_to_B, 101);//here 101 is any request code`
2. wherever you call `finish()` inside `Activity B`, call `setResult(RESULT_OK)`
3. In `Activity A`, override `onActivityResult`.

   `@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == 101) {//this is the request code 
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               startActivity(intent_A_to_C);
       } 
   }`